# Telegram link preview position

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I was wondering if there is any way to place the preview on top of the message.

Currently, regardless of where in the message-string the link is, Telegram will take -always- the first link and generate a preview in the bottom of the final message.

Example:

```
[body text-1]
[link]
[body text-2]
```

Result:

```
[body text-1]
[body text-2]
[link preview]
```

Desired result:

```
[link preview]
[body text-1]
[body text-2]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### No, there's no way to 'move' the [link preview]

Unfortunately Telegram's bot api does not provide any options where to place the [link preview].

The only [link preview] related option is to disable it completely using the `disable_web_page_preview` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The answer above is outdated. For now, you can select the preview position of the web page.

```
link_preview_options: {              
    url: 'https://google.com',
    show_above_text: true
}
```

See docs: https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#linkpreviewoptions